# Page appearing blank but selectable in Safari on iOS9 on first visit

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, safari

So if you visit http://movableink.com/ on Safari on iOS9.

Then click in the header on http://movableink.com/partners

On first visit or slower connections the entire page renders blank in safari.

This is a pretty standard page. There's no specific code to call out that might be causing this. This is a new page with a different css file, it's the first responsive page.

However, the text and content is selectable (but not here) and also if I check it out in the Safari developer inspector when the phone is plugged into a mac there is also nothing notable covering the page.

You may want to look in private browsing, you will want to open up the homepage first and then click on 'Partners'.

What could possibly be causeing this issue of the page disappearing?

Comment: Those links work fine for me on the simulator and real devices. If it does it on the simulator, you could look to use a proxy like Charles on your Mac to debug what is happening. I take it you see the issue on multiple networks and not just when on your WiFi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could reproduce this on my iOS 9 device very well if there was an ad blocker active (in my case: Crystal and Lionz). Without this ad blocker active the page was loading smoothly without a blank screen.

By using another ad blocker (e. g. 1Blocker) the page is also running smoothly.

For me the problem is only related to certain ad blocker apps on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I did some tests, it could be just request timing issues due to either un-optimised server code (like regenerating the whole site stack every first request from a client), or generating CSS.

On first load it is consistently 700ms, regardless of mobile or desktop. Safari will be more sensitive on the mobile as it processes not as many parallel resources after it has a list of url's to get.

If you are using a CMS, check for Optimising / Caching solutions in built into the system and switch that on, see if it changes the load times.

Another alternative is Cloud distributed CDN's such as [Cloud Flare](https://www.cloudflare.com) (free for basic, other plans for more intensive).